# Simple regex match works on rubular but not in IRB

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the string:

```
"hello %{one} there %{two} world"
```

This code does not work:

```
s = "hello %{one} there %{two} world"
r = Regexp.new(/(%{.*?})+/)
m = r.match(s)
m[0] # => "%{one}"
m[1] # => "%{one}" 
m[2] # => nil  # I expected "%{two}"
```

But on [Rubular](http://rubular.com), the same regex `(%{.*?})` works and returns `%{one}` and `%{two}`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method:

```
'hello %{one} there %{two} world'.scan(/(%{.*?})/)
# => [["%{one}"], ["%{two}"]]
```

With non-capturing group:

```
'hello %{one} there %{two} world'.scan(/(?:%{.*?})/)
# => ["%{one}", "%{two}"]
```

**UPDATE** Actually, no grouping is needed.

```
'hello %{one} there %{two} world'.scan(/%{.*?}/)
# => ["%{one}", "%{two}"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But why does the Regexp not return the matches, do you know?

Comment: @Zabba, `String#match` use `Regexp#match` which return `MatchObject`; that represent a single match. I don't know the method design decision history.

Comment: Ah, I see. So making the Regex `/(%{.*}).*(%{.*})/` returns the matches. Thanks!

Comment: @Zabba, I forget to mention that `{` and `}` are needed to be escaped.

Comment: @Zabba, Try `'hello %{one} there %{two} world %{three}'.match(/(%{.*}).*(%{.*})/)` and `'hello %{one} there %{two} world %{three}'.match(/(%{.*?}).*?(%{.*?})/)`

Comment: With `scan` you usually don't want to use captures either, as they'll return arrays of arrays, instead of a single-level array. `'%{one}'.scan(/(%{.*?})+/) # => [["%{one}"]]` vs. `'%{one}'.scan(/(?:%{.*?})+/) # => ["%{one}"]`. The second one uses a non-capturing group `(?:...)`.

Comment: Also, though `{` and `}` have special meaning when specifying the number of items to capture, they don't have to be escaped unless the pattern they're supposed to match looks it'd fit `{[\d,]+}`. The regex engine is pretty smart and can tell the difference. Notice that the examples in my previous comment work without escaping.

Comment: I agree with the Tin Man. Also, get rid of the `+` as it almost certainly doesn't belong. And the grouping, which is just unnecessary. That leaves you with: `/%{.*?}/`, but more efficiently, `/%{[^}]*}/`. Aw hell, I'll just post a new answer I guess.

Comment: @theTinMan, pguardiario, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer.

Comment: It's still overly complex and inefficient, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
'hello %{one} there %{two} world'.scan /%{[^}]*}/
#=> ["%{one}", "%{two}"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for future reference as this is the first question that pops up on Google.

I just hit this problem that my tests worked on Rubular but when I run my code they didn't work.

I was testing something like `/^<regex-goes-here>$/`

Turns out the lines I was testing against the regex ended in carriage returns `\n\r` but I wasnt copy them to Rubular so, of course they wouldn't match.

Hope this helps.